# conditional mutual information

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I have a question about mutual information

$$I(Z ; T/X,Y) = I(T/X,Y ; Z)$$
$T,X,Y,Z$ are random variables

is this statement accurate? 
if it is true 
and I know that I(Z;T/X,Y) = H(Z/X,Y) - H(Z/T,X,Y)
how can I analyze I(T/X,Y ; Z) ?

Comment: What is the definition of $I(T|X,Y; Z)$?  This looks non-standard.  You can define mutual information $I(X;Y)$ between two random variables $X, Y$.  You can define conditional mutual information $I(X;Y|Z)$, which is understood as information between $X$ and $Y$, everything conditioned on $Z$.  I don't think it makes sense to consider mutual information between two random variables, only one of which is conditioned on a third. More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information